# How can I mirror 2 desktop screens onto 2 additional desktop screens?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Trying to find a solution for creating a good "pair programming" environment. One suggested solution involved:

- 1 Desktop
- 4 Desktop Monitors
- 2 Keyboards
- 2 Mice

Where, you essentially get two identical setups:

- 2 Desktop Monitors
- 1 Keyboard
- 1 Mouse

Where everything is mirrored. Two people driving the same machine.

I don't believe you can accomplish this with out of the box window settings/features, but is there a way to accomplish this at all? With third party software? With some creative hacking?

Comment: What about using to splitters that just duplicate the signal? One splitter connects the two left monitors to your graphic card and the other one the two right monitors. Windows recognizes the two splitters as two screens which allows you to use the extended display option. In times when VGA connection was user, those adapters existed. Nowadays, adapters often parse information on both connect monitors to Windows which does not solve your problem ... . Alternatively, there is software available like "Actual Multiple Monitors".